# Bayes theorem in advertising

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian, marketing

I am new to Bayes theorem, and was wondering if anyone can guide me through this question.

An advertising agency want to analyze the advertisements for a product. They want to target people from all age groups. They show 5 advertisement videos to 200 people. The following is the data on how many people from each group liked which videos.

[image]

A new consumer is shown the videos and he likes videos 2, 3 and 5. Which age group is he most likely to belong to?

Comment: You should probably add the [tag:self-study] tag and indicate where you are stuck with Bayes theorem in this particular case.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! As posted, this question is too vague. Please clarify where you want to use Bayes.

Comment: Bayes theorem is a fundamental law of probability that can be exploited in the most varied cases. Whenever you are using probability, understanding Bayes theorem can be of help. This is not always the case in machine learning, as many machine learning methods do not actually involve probability, and knowledge of probability laws is not required for their application.

Comment: It seems that someone posted some homework, got an answer and replaced the original question with something else. What is to be done in these situations? I still have the original text. Should I add it to my answer, or just remove the answer altogether? Thanks for the help.

Comment: @jpneto: I've rolled back the edit so your answer remains relevant. For future reference please read the wiki for the 'self-study' tag - we help people get unstuck rather than do the exercise for them. And if you see it happen again that someone changes a question enough to render an answer irrelevant, please flag the q. for moderator attention.

Answer (score 2):

```
# the collected data
ages.16.35 <- c(20,30,60,15,90)
ages.36.55 <- c(15,50,30,20,40)
ages.older <- c(35,30,10,10, 5)

total.16.35 <- 100
total.36.55 <-  60
total.older <-  40
```

Let the new data be coded as $D=\{v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_5\}$ where $v_i$ is 1 if the video $i$ was liked, 0 otherwise. In the example you give, that is $D=\{0,1,1,0,1\}$.

```
# the new data
new.data <- c(0,1,1,0,1)
```

Concerning video $j$ for age category $i$, we model its binary response as a Bernoulli,

$$v_j \sim \text{Bern}(\theta_{ij})$$

$\theta_{ij}$ means the probability of liking video $j$ for category $i$.

I will assume that, for a given age category, liking a video is independent of liking or not any other video.

Now we consider the existence of three models, $\mathcal{M_i}$, one per age category.

Applying Bayes theorem,

$$p(\mathcal{M}_i~|~D) \propto p(D~|~\mathcal{M}_i)p(\mathcal{M}_i)$$

The priors for models $\mathcal{M}_i$ can be either the uniform $p(\mathcal{M_i}) = 1/3$ or we assume that the collected data is representative of the company's clients and use,

$$p(\mathcal{M}_1) = \frac{100}{200} = 0.5; p(\mathcal{M}_2) = 0.3; p(\mathcal{M}_3) = 0.2$$

In the next computations, I'm using this second option.

For the likelihood, we plug the Bernoulli probability mass functions together with the independence assumption and get:

$$p(D~|~\mathcal{M}_i) = \prod_{j=1}^5 \theta_{ij}^{v_j} (1-\theta_{ij})^{1-v_j}$$
Ok, let's R it:

```
thetas <- matrix(c(c(ages.16.35)/total.16.35,
                   c(ages.36.55)/total.36.55,
                   c(ages.older)/total.older), nrow=3, byrow=TRUE)

priors <- c(total.16.35, total.36.55, total.older)
priors <- priors / sum(priors)

likelihood <- function(D, i, thetas) {
  prod(thetas[i,]^D * (1-thetas[i,])^(1-D))
}

likelihoods <- sapply(1:3, function(i) likelihood(new.data,i,thetas))

posteriors <- likelihoods * priors
posteriors <- posteriors / sum(posteriors)

round(100*posteriors, 2) # in percentages
```

The output:

```
[1] 56.67 42.87  0.45
```

If you want to dig deeper in the Bayesian rabbit hole, use the collected data to assign priors for the $\theta_{ij}$ parameters. The model would become,

$$v_{ij} \sim \text{Bern}(\theta_{ij})$$

$$\theta_{ij} \sim \text{Beta}(k_{ij}+1,n_i-k_{ij}+1)$$

where $k_{ij}$ is the total of likes for video $j$ for age category $i$, and $n_i$ is the total of persons at age category $i$.

One last thing. The probabilities that you get after the model fit have uncertainties (as described by the posteriors distributions, if you use Stan or similar software tools). The decision of assigning the new data to an age category is not the model's responsibility. Decision comes after inference in a Bayesian workflow.

You need to think if the costs of false positives are the same for all age categories. Perhaps assigning an older person to a younger category is twice as costly. That should have impact in your final classification.

Comment: as I understand there is no information about videos 1 and 4 so these two zeros should be dropped